# Remove directory path from grep -r output

Tags: grep, txt

I am running grep -r to look for the context of a word in multiple files.

I am using -r to do it recursively, -i to ignore case and -C to get lines below and above:

```
grep -r -i -C 10 --group-separator="==========" "29/04/2020" "$dir" >> output.txt
```

In my output, however, I get the filenames before the match, like:

```
../data/filename1.txt-       (other text)
../data/filename1.txt-        29/04/2020 is the date for etc
../data/filename1.txt-       (other text)                                                                                      
==========
../data/different_filename.txt-       (other text)
../data/different_filename.txt-        something in 29/04/2020
../data/different_filename.txt-       (other text)
```

I would like as output just:

```
(other text)
29/04/2020 is the date for etc
(other text)                                                                                      
==========
(other text)
something in 29/04/2020
(other text)
```

Do you know how I could alter the grep -r command to exclude the filepaths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep -h`, as described in [man grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

> `-h`
> `--no-filename`
> Suppress the prefixing of file names on output. This is the default when there is only one file (or only standard input) to
> search.

**SEE ALSO:**
[Get `grep` to not output file name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204607/13411)